# Regex to replace the word between two character/s

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace characters between two string/s with below code:

```
<tr <?php echo "class = 'link_id_$row->link_id key_id_$row->key_id'";?>>
<td>
<?php echo form_input('target_keyword', $row->key_name, 
  "class = 'link_id_$row->link_id key_id_$row->key_id validate[required] edit_keyword' id='target_links_$row->key_id'");
?>
<?php echo form_hidden('client_id', $client_id);?>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo form_dropdown('target_links', $links_data, $row->link_id,
  'class="target_urls validate[required]" id="target_links_$row->key_id"');
?>
</td>
<td class="center">
<?php echo "<input type='hidden' value='$row->key_id' class='key_id'/>"; ?>
<?php echo "<input type='hidden' value='$row->link_id' class='link_id'/>"; ?>
<?php echo form_submit('edit_keyword', '', 'id="edit_keyword" class="edit"');?>
<?php echo form_submit('delete_keyword', '', 'id="delete_keyword" class="delete"');?>
</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way we can replace anything in between "row" and "'" ?

Comment: I don't see "row" and "'" in the code - what line?  And the answer is probably yes if you can isolate the characters to just that line.

Comment: Is row <tr/> ? Or what? And with what do you want to replace it with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem with single quote (') and double quote (") using wrong way. First you understand the difference of these and use in proper manner.

Please try the below code

```
$obj_1 = "$row->link_id";
$obj_2 = "$row->key_id";
$class_1 = "link_id_$obj_1";
$class_2 = "key_id_$obj_2";

<tr <?php echo "class = $class_1 $class_2";?>>
```